# Problema em setar uma lista em um singleton

Tags: java

bom eu criei uma lista com um select no banco de dados
e queria setar ela no meu singleton para poder utilizar ela em todas as telas:
codigo do meu DAO:

```
 public List<Requisicao> pegarRequisicoesUser() {
    List<Requisicao> requisicoes = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM equipamento_requisicao equipreq INNER JOIN equipamento_user equipuser ON (equipreq.idequipamento_user = equipuser.id_equipamento_do_usuario)  INNER JOIN usuario user ON (user.id_usuario=equipuser.idusuario) INNER JOIN equipamentos equip ON (equip.id_equipamentos = equipuser.idequipamentos) INNER JOIN detalhe_status dStatus ON (dStatus.idequipamento_requisicao= equipreq.id_requisicao) INNER JOIN status_requisicao statusreq on (statusreq.id_status= dStatus.idstatus) INNER JOIN permissao p ON(user.idpermissao= p.id_permissao) INNER JOIN departamentos dp ON(user.iddepartamento = dp.id_departamentos) INNER JOIN chefe_departamento cp ON(dp.id_departamentos = cp.iddepartamento) where statusreq.categoria='Ativo' and user.id_usuario = "+ Sessao.getInstancia().getUsuario().getId() + " ";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {       


            //CHEFES DE DEPARTAMENTOS            
            // usuario chefe depart
            Usuario usuarioChefe = new Usuario();
            usuarioChefe.setId(rs.getLong("cp.idusuario")); 
            // usuario chefe depart
            // departamento chefe
            Departamento departamentoChefe = new Departamento();
            departamentoChefe.setId_departamento(rs.getInt("cp.iddepartamento"));
            // departamento chefe
            // INICIO DA TABELA CHEFE
            ChefesDepartamentos chefes = new ChefesDepartamentos();
            chefes.setId_chefe(rs.getInt("cp.id_chefe"));
            chefes.setCpIdusuario(usuarioChefe);
            chefes.setCpIddepartamento(departamentoChefe);
            // FIM TABELA CHEFE
            // FIM    // PARA ESTUDOS

            // INICIO TABELA USUARIO 

            //Permissao Usuario
            Permissao permissaoUsuario = new Permissao();
            permissaoUsuario.setId_permissao(rs.getInt("user.idpermissao"));
            permissaoUsuario.setCategoria_permissao(rs.getString("p.categoria"));
            //fim permissao usuario
            //incio departamento usuario
            Departamento departamentoUsuario = new Departamento();
            departamentoUsuario.setId_departamento(rs.getInt("dp.id_departamentos"));
            departamentoUsuario.setNome_setor(rs.getString("dp.nome_setor"));
            //FIM
            // usuario
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.setNome(rs.getString("user.nome"));
            usuario.setId(rs.getLong("user.id_usuario"));
            usuario.setMatricula(rs.getString("user.matricula"));
            usuario.setLogin(rs.getString("user.login"));
            usuario.setpUsuario(permissaoUsuario);
            usuario.setdUsuario(departamentoUsuario);
            // FIM TABELA USUARIO               
            //equipamento // equipamento user tabelas
            Equipamentos equipamento = new Equipamentos();
            equipamento.setEquipamento_nome(rs.getString("equip.equipamento_nome"));
            equipamento.setSerial_equipamento(rs.getString("equipuser.serial_equipamento"));
            equipamento.setId_equipamento_do_Usuario(rs.getLong("equipreq.idequipamento_user"));
            //status tabela
            Status status = new Status();
            status.setCategoria(rs.getString("statusreq.categoria"));
            status.setIdstatus(rs.getInt("statusreq.id_status"));
            //status detalhes tabela
            Usuario usuarioStatus = new Usuario();//id do usuaro na tabela detalhes status
            usuarioStatus.setId(rs.getLong("dStatus.idusuario"));
            StatusDetalhes statusDetalhes = new StatusDetalhes();
            statusDetalhes.setId_statusdetalhes(rs.getLong("dStatus.id_statusdetalhes"));
            statusDetalhes.setData_status(rs.getTimestamp("dStatus.data"));
            statusDetalhes.setObservacao_status(rs.getString("dStatus.observacao"));
            statusDetalhes.setIdUsuario(usuarioStatus);
            statusDetalhes.setIdStatus(status);
            // Id da requisicao na tabela detalhes status
            Requisicao requisicaoStatus = new Requisicao();
            requisicaoStatus.setId(rs.getLong("dStatus.idequipamento_requisicao"));
            //requisicao tabela
            Requisicao req = new Requisicao();
            req.setId(rs.getLong("equipreq.id_requisicao"));
            req.setNome(rs.getString("equipreq.nome"));
            req.setData_criada(rs.getTimestamp("equipreq.data_requisicao"));
            req.setMotivo(rs.getString("equipreq.observacao"));
            req.setReqEquipamento(equipamento);
            req.setReqStatus(statusDetalhes);
            req.setReqUsuario(usuario);
            req.setReqStatus_Detalhes(statusDetalhes);
            req.setChefes(chefes);
            requisicoes.add(req);
        }
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RequisicaoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }

    return requisicoes;
}
```

e no meu singleton eu fiz:

```
private List<Requisicao> requisicaolist;
public List<Requisicao> getRequisicaolist() {
    return requisicaolist;
}

public void setRequisicaolist(List<Requisicao> requisicaolist) {
    this.requisicaolist = requisicaolist;
}
```

mas eu não sei como eu vou conseguir acessar essa lista em qualquer parte do programa

```
RequisicaoDAO dao = new RequisicaoDAO();
aSessao.getInstancia().setRequisicaolist(dao.pegarRequisicoesUser());
```

eu setei ela 
no meu main
como eu conseguiria pegar dados dessa lista?

Comment: acho que não é bem singleton o que vc quer... singleton é para manter uma mesma instância de um classe, e vc quer manter uma lista, isso seria mais simples, uma lista *static* ou ainda melhor, por se tratar de dados do banco, um cache por exemplo, que pode expirar

Comment: tipo ao logar eu guardo todos os dados da classe usuario todos os dados da classe equipamento todos os dados da classe departamentos todos do chefe departamentos, eu queria guardar todos as requisições criadas por esse usuario em uma lista quando ele logar.

Comment: você poderia me ajudar? Não sei como fazer um cache  e como acessar ele em qualquer stage do programa.

Comment: isso que precisa definitivamente não é singleton... é uma aplicação web?

Comment: Não é desktop..

Comment: Eu só tou querendo guardar todos os dados do banco de dados em suas respectivas classes no java.

Comment: Para criar tipo uma "sessão"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode transformar o objeto em uma *static* para ter uma única instância, e verificar se já foi instanciado no get:

```
private static List<Requisicao> requisicaolist;

public List<Requisicao> getRequisicaolist() {
    if (requisicaolist == null) {
        RequisicaoDAO dao = new RequisicaoDAO();
        requisicaolist = dao.pegarRequisicoesUser();
    }
    return requisicaolist;
}
```

Assim, ao usar o `get`, se a lista ainda não foi instanciada, chama o método `pegarRequisicoesUser()`, senão só retorna o valor que já está armazenado, fazendo com que consulte o banco só uma vez.